# Show $\int_A g\ d\mu = \int_A f\ d\mu$ for $A$ in a sub sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space with $f\in L^1$. Let $\Sigma'\subset\Sigma$ be a sub sigma algebra. I want to show the existence of $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is $\Sigma'$ measurable with
$$ \int_A g\ d\mu = \int_A f\ d\mu $$
for $A\in\Sigma'$.

My attempt. I want to take $g=f$ a.e. so that the integral condition is easily satisfied. However this does not make $g$ $\Sigma'$-measurable, only $\Sigma$ measurable. To fix this, I'm thinking to take 
$$ g = \begin{cases}
\infty,\ \text{ on null sets in }\Sigma' \\
f,\ \text{ else}
\end{cases} $$
Will this make $g$ $\Sigma'$ measurable? I.e. is $g^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])\in\Sigma'$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$? I don't think so but I'm stuck with what to do if not.

Comment: You may not define $g$ this way. For example, if you pick $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on an interval $I$, then, $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for any $x\in I$. Thus, $g\equiv \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

First, define $\nu$ on $(X, \Sigma')$ by
$$\nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu$$
for all $A \in \Sigma'$. Let $\mu'$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $(X, \Sigma')$.

We have $\nu \ll \mu'$, so by Radon-Nikodym, there exists an integrable function $g$ on the measurable space $(X, \Sigma')$ that satisfies
$$\nu(A) = \int_A g d\mu'$$
for all $A \in \Sigma'$. But $\int_A g d\mu' = \int_A g d\mu$ just by the definition of the integral, and so
$$\int_A gd\mu = \int_A f d\mu.$$

Incidentally, in probability $g$ is called a conditional expectation and so we proved that conditional expectations always exist.

Comment: I guess you meant $\nu\ll\mu'$

Comment: Ah I see. I was going about it all wrong. I think that should also be $\nu<<\mu'$ in the original post?

Comment: @AndréPorto Yes, thanks. Edited.